# What's a good translation for "outcome measures"?

Tags: translation, word-choice, english-to-german

For example in the sentence:

> Outcome measures for this study include three-year-survival rate and relapse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Outcome measures"* does not translate easily. One possibility is:

> Das Ergebnis wurde anhand von ... bestimmt."

In a medical study - as it seems to be the case here - we can replace *"Ergebnis"* by a more precise "*Behandlungsergebnis*" or *"Therapieerfolg"*.

Comment: +1 for "Ergebnis(se)", which may be specified further

Answer (score 2):

The most common german term for this seems

> [Ergebnisgröße](http://www.biomedsearch.com/nih/Outcome-assessment-in-total-knee/15754228.html) (Vernacular Title)

and means a (measurement) **quantity to judge the result**, not a result itself. It's not only used in medical studies. Similar to *output quantity*, it's a quantity to **evaluate** something. For example in a clinical study, an outcome measure could be *Patientenzufriedenheit, Gelenkbeweglichkeit* (nach Anwendung einer neuen Operationsmethode, die evaluiert und mit anderen verglichen werden muss), *Rückfallquote* (bei neuen Suchttherapien)... So these are quantities you **define yourself** in the context of a specific study/meta-study and also how these quantities are measured exactly (**Operationalization problem**). There are a thousand ways to measure *Patientenzufriedenheit*, so it's crucial to find an objective one, while something like *Blutdruck* has a fixed and known method.

Comment: Note that _Ergebnisgröße_ at that link is the translation of _outcome variable_, not of _outcome measure_. (Maybe that doesn't matter.)

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to *Ergebnis* for *outcome* (as suggested [by Takkat](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2523/whats-a-good-translation-for-outcome-measures/2524#2524) and [by Hauser](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2523/whats-a-good-translation-for-outcome-measures/2533#2533)) I propose *Ziel*. [On Linguee](http://www.linguee.de/englisch-deutsch/uebersetzung/outcome+measures.html) I found the versions

> Zielparameter, Zielkriterien, Zielgrößen

for *outcome measures*.

Answer (score 0):

Ich würde "Metriken" für "measures" vorschlagen. In der Summe **vielleicht** "Ergebnismetriken".

Comment: Note that *"Metrik"* may be something else:http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Metrik

Comment: Good point, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @elena: It sounded good to me at first, too, but I think I was confused because it sounded so much like the English metrics, which can be used that way, and I knew it was a valid German word - it took me a while to remember that as a German word it means a different thing.